# Is it necessary to reduce requests for local resources in phonegap apps?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, cordova

Using PhoneGap to write web apps, there will be many requests to resources like css, JavaScript, images, etc. This resources are available at local (within the apk package for example).
In web development, such requests should be reduced to reduce latency. Is it still necessary to do so in PhoneGap apps (e.g., combine scripts, put scripts to page end, using icon/image sprites)?

Answer (score 0):

As long as everything is local you can focus more on reusable code and less on performance. HOWEVER, you still want to ensure that the what you are doing isnt going to hurt UI performance. For example, if you are loading many many small images on a single screen, it might be better to use image sprites. It will really come down to your use-case and testing.

My apps generally have one main .js file that contains functions that are frequently used across pages and also on .js file for each page that has functions only that page uses. Same goes for my .css files.